# How do I add HTML markup to the title?

Tags: 8, views, theming

I am trying to alter my title to include html. I have tried the following

```php
function MODULENAME_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'products_test') {
    foreach($view->result as $value) {
      $value->_object->set('title', 'test - <b>My new Title</b>');
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs the title as `test - <b>My new Title</b>`, rather than rendering the text as HTML markup.

I tried passing the title to `decode_entities()`, but nothing changed.

I am using the *Full content* mode, rather than the *Fields* mode, if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to alter html, generally you'll be working with [hook_preprocess_hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.8.x) or a [twig template override](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/working-with-twig-templates). This is the case for views as well. In the case of views, the template that renders the title is `views-view.html.twig`.

EDIT: Fastest way is just to use #markup

```php
function my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = [
    '#markup' => 'test - <b>My new Title</b>'
  ];
}
```

So if you wanted to render the title with a **b** tag, you could do:

```php
function my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $existing_title = $variables['title'];
  $variables['title'] = [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<b>{{ title }}</b>',
    '#context' => [
      'title' => $existing_title,
    ],
  ];
}
```

However, it's maybe not ideal to use tags for presentation and better to use classes and CSS styling. If you just want to add a CSS class to target, you could do a similar thing:

```php
function my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $existing_title = $variables['title'];
  $variables['title'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'views-title', // or whatever 
      ],
    ],
    '#value' => $existing_title
  ];
}
```

Both `#container` and `#inline_template` are [render elements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements), and there are a lot available to you.

Of course, depending on what your theme and other modules are doing, the existing `$variables['title']` might not just be a string, so you may need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the details replied. But I am looking to but HTML elements in the Title not just wrap the title in a class.

Comment: Sorry, misread. Updated my answer to include how to use #markup

Comment: Please feel free to revert my edit if you don't like it. But better recommend `inline_template` instead of `html_tag` which should rather be used for `script` tags for example.

Comment: Actually I didn't know about `inline_template` -- that's great! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

To change a view title, you can implement `hook_preprocess_views_view()`, which is what the *Views UI* module does, with [`views_ui_preprocess_views_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views_ui%21views_ui.module/function/views_ui_preprocess_views_view/8.9.x).

```php
// Render title for the admin preview.
if (!empty($view->live_preview)) {
  $variables['title'] = [
    '#markup' => $view->getTitle(),
  ];
}
```

Using that code avoids the HTML markup used in the title is escaped/sanitized.

When the *View UI* module is installed, and you want to set the same view title in the the admin preview, the hook implemented by your module needs to be invoked after the one implemented by the *View UI* module. Keep in mind that `views_ui_preprocess_views_view()` uses also the following code.

```php
if (!empty($view->live_preview) && \Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('contextual')) {
  $view->setShowAdminLinks(FALSE);
  foreach (['title', 'header', 'exposed', 'rows', 'pager', 'more', 'footer', 'empty', 'attachment_after', 'attachment_before'] as $section) {
    if (!empty($variables[$section])) {
      $variables[$section] = [
        '#theme' => 'views_ui_view_preview_section',
        '#view' => $view,
        '#section' => $section,
        '#content' => $variables[$section],
        '#theme_wrappers' => [
          'views_ui_container',
        ],
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => [
            'contextual-region',
          ],
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

As side note, the default [views-view.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view.html.twig/8.9.x) template used by the Views module used two template variables more: `title_prefix` and `title_suffix`.

```
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {{ title }}
  {{ title_suffix }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are either clunky, don't cover all cases, or open security vulnerabilities.  Instead, check out [HTML Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title) module.